# How do you create an account on NEAR?

Tags: nearprotocol

In the wallet.near.org you can restore an account but how do you create a brand new named account like `foo.near`?

Answer (score 2):

The UI in the wallet doesn't appear ready yet but this can be done via the CLI by calling the contract deployed on the `near` root account. Here's the command:

```
near call near create_account '{"new_account_id": "NAME.near", "new_public_key": "YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY"}' --amount 10 --accountId YOUR_MASTER_ACCT [--useLedgerKey] --gas 100000000000000
```

where:

- `NAME.near` is the account you want to create
- `YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY` is a public key you've generated with a Ledger Nano S or X following the instructions on docs.near.org
- `YOUR_MASTER_ACCT` is an account you control, to which you've given access to `near-cli` using the `near login` command or which you control via a Ledger Nano
- `--amount 10` is the initial amount you want to send from `YOUR_MASTER_ACCT`
- use `--useLedgerKey` if you control `YOUR_MASTER_ACCT` via a Ledger Nano

Answer (score 0):

UI to create accounts is now fully live at https://wallet.near.org/create

There is one extra step where you have to fund temporary account from exchange.